# How do i get this kind of time format when "now" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a need to put this kind of format when doing some action:

```
2014-11-19T10:07:25.000Z
```

Like when in a press of an action button, i need to alert the current time in the format above, in javascript, plain and simple...

What is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the returned format of `toISOString` method of `Date` instance.

```
new Date().toISOString(); //"2014-12-06T08:10:55.713Z"
```

More on date and time iso, see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and [**wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Sure, but `new Date(Date.now())` is a bit convoluted (why not just `new Date()`?)

Comment: @Juhana Yep, I also realized that :)